# Compile multiple c++ files with .txt file?

Tags: c++, command-line, compiler-errors, compilation, atom-editor

I've read that it's possible to compile multiple linked c++ files together using the command line `g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp` and so on.

But my question is : is there a way to write that text in a .txt file so it can easily be updated? Because I feel that writting every file names is very long and not so practical...

++Is there also any way to compile multiple c++ files with Atom Editor? I'm using the [gpp-compiler](https://atom.io/packages/gpp-compiler) package but I can't find a way to make it work...

Comment: It sounds like you want a Makefile - have you looked into that?

Comment: Should look up how to create a makefile.

Comment: I'd recommend CMake instead of using a Makefile. CMake is the de facto standard. And, built-in, cmake lets you build without rebuilding files that didn't change

Comment: Agree CMake is a marvelous tool, but you picked a very silly reason for it to be better than make, Justin.

Comment: *"And, built-in, cmake lets you build without rebuilding files that didn't change"* that's what make has been doing for last 40 years or so!

Comment: I think I'm gonna go for a .cmd file for now, but I'll sure look into Cmake in the future (for bigger projects). Thanks to all of you!

Comment: @user4581301 yes. CMake does the job (and does have the mindshare in their favour - and we use it at work - it *does* work).. but, have you ever looked at their implementation? That parser is horrible (IMHO). And the language they have created is inconsistent, full of weird corner cases and just plain back asswards behaviour. In *my* oppinion, something like [SCons](http://scons.org/) solves the problem a *lot* nicer and uses an established scripting language (Python) rather than invent their own (fscked up bastard language). But, that's just my opinion.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Add your commands in a text file and give extension as ".cmd ", which executes the commands in it when you open the file.

eg:

```
cd c:
cd users/document/    //your file path
g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp
```

By doing this you can execute the file from anywhere.

save as "filename.cmd"

List of Executable File Extensions:
https://www.lifewire.com/list-of-executable-file-extensions-2626061

Comment: if you make it clear what you actually wanted I can update my answer.

Comment: I guess that be enough for now, I don't have a project that big thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

What you want is a *build system* where you can specify the source files of your application, their dependencies, any compiler flags needed etc.

There are *many* different build systems available. Some of the more popular ones are [SCons](http://scons.org), [CMake](https://cmake.org) and [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) - I'd suggest you read up on them and pick the one that best suits *your* needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Will definitly be usefull!